# Can't restart Python script os.exec*()

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, os.execl

I basically want to restart the current script I'm running. So to do that I need to use some of the **os.exec*()** functions. But I don't want to pass in any parameters, I'm not sure how to actually start the program.

`os.execl(str(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "")` returns an error because I can't leave the second argument blank.